# Using jsp variable inside java code in jsp file

Tags: java, ajax, jsp, base64

I want to convert an stream in jsp file to byte array and then this byte array to base64.

I am trying to this is .jsp file as

```
'<%byte[] bytes = IOUtils.toByteArray(result); 
String base64String = Base64.encodeBase64URLSafeString(bytes);%>';
```

where `result` is response of an `ajax call`

```
$.ajax({
    type : 'POST',
    url : url,
    data : requestParams,
    success : function(result) {
        '<%byte[] bytes = IOUtils.toByteArray(result); 
        String base64String = Base64.encodeBase64URLSafeString(bytes);%>';
        debugger
    },
    error : function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        sleep(1);
        dialog.dialog("close");
        console.log("Some Error.");
        showAjaxResponse("FAILED : Tried to access.");
    }
});
```

The used url in the ajax call is returning an InputStream.

I think I am missing something.

Comment: The jsp code is "interpreted" before any JS code in that JSP, so this can not work. Where do you "post", if that is something you own, maybe you could change the output format, if it's something *external*, maybe you could wrap the "post" in a custom servlet

Comment: Isn't there any other way to achieve the same in the jsp file?

Comment: the url is internal,  output is currently a stream. Actually I need to get Image from some datastore. So I am converting the image in the form of stream to serve the response.

Comment: Why do you want to do this in JSP. Delegate it to Servlet